# How to redirect user to its organization’s webpage

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I’m using Firebase for user authentication.

Let’s say I have several organizations using an application and each organization has its own number of employees. I wonder what’s the best pattern to redirect to the user to its organization’s instance of my web application.

My database has the following paths/tables :

```
/OrganizationA/somedata
/organizationB/somedata
/organizationC/somedata
```

Let’s say Alex belongs to organization A, he goes to mywebsite/login and enters his username and password. How can I tell that I should redirect him to organization A ?

My intuition is that I should have a table

```
/profiles/userId/somedata
```

So that when the user successfully logs in, I check in this table what organization he has permission to access and then redirect him to that organization, again assuming he has permission.

However, under very organization I have an employee table that has all the information pertaining to the employee

```
/OrganizationA/employees/userId/userInfo
```

I wonder if there is a better approach to this?
As I mentioned, I’m using Firebase APIs to manage registrations, login, authstate, etc.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Firebase for user authentication, you should be able to maintain the user's profile within Firebase itself as user properties.

For each organisation that the user is eligible to have access they can have a corresponding organisation identifier maintained within Firebase as a user property.

For e.g. User X to have the following properties

> organisation_keys: { OrganisationA, OrganisationB}

User Y to have the following properties

> organisation_keys: { OrganisationC}

Once a user gets authenticated via Firebase and get to your web application, you can access the firebase authenticated user's properties within your application and find which organisation they belong to by the properties they have & decide where to redirect the user.

**Update:**

Meanwhile, the solution that you had described in the question is also not a bad one. You can maintain the access permission details of the users within a table
in your own application.

If you have plans to replace Firebase Authentication with a different Federated Authentication provider in the future then it may make more sense to keep the user profile within your own tables in your application.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much. It was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

You don't check permission, you read properties of the signed in user then use the value of that property, e.g. `organization: "red"` to `window.location.path = "/red"`.

The permissions, insofar as you mean Firebase Security Rules, determine whether Firebase will allow read or write of requested data or not.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying Ron. :) very helpful.